# can you delete keyframes at regular intervals in a given range?

Tags: animation, keyframes, interpolation

the BVH I imported has keyframes on almost every frame.. i want to edit like 300 frames and i want 1 keyframe for every 30 frames for those 300.. Im currently doing it by placing 2 markers between 29frames and selecting everything between them adn deleting it... but i have to do this 10 times.. is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but maybe it can help : there is an (integrated) addon, Simplify Curves. It reduces the number of keyframes, preserving the general shape of the curve.

- Activate the addon (search "simplify" and click the checkbox next to "Add Curve: Simplify Curves")
- Select your F-curves
- type <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> then "simplify", select "simplify F-curve"
- adjust the "distance error" setting. Warning, it's located in the Operator panel **in the 3d view, not in the F-Curve editor**

Answer (score 1):

I was looking the same solution too but no luck. I created a script myself just to do that. Here you are https://github.com/kuoliangkwong/blender-remove-interval-keyframes

It's not very user friendly at the moment, and require some technical steps, but it does the work. Will add in UI if have time

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. Since the source code is only 23 lines long (at least at this stage), would you please insert the current version of your script directly in the answer? To avoid the risk of links "rotting", we tend to keep all the relevant information on the site ([more on this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/368912)). You can of course, in addition to that, link to your repository, saying that the maintained version can be found there. Don't worry: the license of StackExchange is [CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)